# problem with roscreate-pkg

Tags: ros, roscreate-pkg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi!

I have a problem in a terminal when I trying create a new package within the folder nxt.  The message I get is:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/ros/electric/ros/bin/roscreate-pkg", line 35, in 
roscreate.roscreatepkg.roscreatepkg_main()
File "/opt/ros/electric/ros/tools/roscreate/src/roscreate/roscreatepkg.py", line 126, in roscreatepkg_main
create_package(package, author_name(), depends, uses_roscpp=uses_roscpp, uses_rospy=uses_rospy)
File "/opt/ros/electric/ros/tools/roscreate/src/roscreate/roscreatepkg.py", line 63, in create_package
os.makedirs(p)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/opt/ros/electric/stacks/nxt/learning_nxt'

how I can solve?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28909/problem-with-roscreate-pkg/) by [keira](https://answers.ros.org/users/1884/keira/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2012-03-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [keira](https://answers.ros.org/users/1884/keira/) on 2012-03-03**:
thanks,

I was just following the tutorial nxt, and as there are working on nxt folder, because I believed they were working with that of ros, but I see that I have to create one with the same name in my workspace, I'm right?

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2012-03-04**:
That should work.  For clarity I might suggest that you not use things with the same name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It is not recommended to work in /opt.  Those packages are installed on your system and shared with all users, and the directories are read only except as root.  If you follow the first few [ROS Tutorials](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials) they will guide you through creating a package in an area where you can write.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-03-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2